# What's the Pythonic way to map with multiprocessing.Pool while also appending to the iterator?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

It seems a common pattern to consume a queue with a pool of processes, i.e.

```
Pool(2).map(f, xs)
```

but where the body of f may append to the items being mapped over, e.g.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

xs = [0]

def f(n):
    global xs
    if n < 10:
        xs.append(n + 1)
    return n

Pool(2).map(f, xs)
```

Expecting to return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I realize it's possible to build this "[manually](https://gist.github.com/anfedorov/7dae4d7dc7a959ae438b2fa33b343f6c)" with the primitives provided by mt, but it seems like a common enough pattern that there must be a common solution. Do you know of one?

Comment: Thanks — it can't be iterated over, though, and I that I realize I can use it to do something manual [1], but it seems so darn complicated for such a simple and common task. 1: https://testdriven.io/blog/developing-an-asynchronous-task-queue-in-python/#multiprocessing-queue

Comment: Each process runs in its own memory-space, so you can't share access to a global variable like `xs`. See [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class that does it from primitives like:

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Process


class PoolQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.num_procs = n

    def map(self, f, args):
        payloads = JoinableQueue()
        procs = []

        def add_task(arg):
            payloads.put(arg)

        def process_task():
            while True:
                pl = payloads.get()
                f(pl, add_task)
                payloads.task_done()

        for arg in args:
            add_task(arg)

        procs = [Process(target=process_task) for _ in range(self.num_procs)]
        for p in procs:
            p.start()

        payloads.join()
        for p in procs:
            p.kill()
```

To test it, run —

```
from time import sleep
from random import random


def pause():
    sleep(random() / 100)


def process(payload, add_task):
    print(payload)
    pause()
    if payload:
        add_task(payload[:-1])
    return payload


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(1):
        PoolQueue(2).map(
            process,
            [
                'abcdefghij',
                '0123456789',
                '!@#$%^&*()',
            ],
        )
```

One problem here is that it deadlocks the queue grows >32767 tasks. The `gevent.queue.JoinableQueue` handles this better, but that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @martineau's suggestion, your code could be updated to:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def f(n, xs, xn):
    if n < 10:
        xn.append(n)
        xs.append(n + 1)
        xn.append(n)
        xs.append(n + 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        xs = manager.list()
        xn = manager.list()
        with mp.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            pool.starmap(f, [(n, xs, xn) for n in range(20)])
        print(xn)
        print(xs)
```

This prints

```
[3, 0, 3, 0, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 9, 7, 9, 8, 8]
[4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 3, 7, 4, 7, 8, 8, 10, 9, 11, 9, 10]
```

for which you see you have no guarantee the order in which n values are produced gets preserved.

EDIT:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def f(n):
    thresh = 10
    if max(xs) <= thresh and n < thresh:
        xs.append(n + 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        xs = manager.list([0])
        with mp.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
            pool.map(f, range(20))
        print(sorted(xs))
```

This one prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that doesn't quite do what I want. If it did, then changing the `< 10` to `< 1000` should result in about 100x the output.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Have you modified the value inside the range function?

Comment: I modified my question to simplify the example and add an output for an input of `xs = [0]` -- does that make more sense?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully, it matches better what you expect. Note that you still need to vary both the condition on `n` and the value you give in `range`. The condition on `max(xs)` is to avoid any higher number being incorporated because of an out-of-order execution.

Comment: Sorry, no -- I would expect this output if instead of passing in `range(20)`, you passed in `[0]`, since the function `f` would then call `xs.append(1)`, which the map function would process and call `xs.append(2)`, etc.

I'll add the best answer I have w.r.t. code that does something like this, but I'm still at a loss why this isn't something that can be done using built-in's.

Comment: But, if you pass in [0], how is `map` supposed to know how many tasks each process will have to perform? In your version, you include the condition in the actual body of the function (`f`), so map does not know how many tasks each process should execute...

Comment: map should perform tasks until all tasks have finished and the task queue is empty.